# JFrame window coordinates in error

Tags: java, swing, plot, graphics, jframe

When one plots points on the JFrame, one naturally assumes that (0,0) corresponds the the top-left pixel available below the tab, and that (Max_x, Max_y) corresponds  to the bottom-right pixel in the Frame. However it seems that the (0,0) actually is hidden in the area where the tab is. For instance, if I write the following code to draw a diagonal line between the top-left corner and the bottom-right corner,

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends JFrame{


    public Test() { 
        setSize(960, 960);
        setTitle("Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 960, 960);
    }

}
```

I get the following

[image: Example]

And as we can see, the top-left of the line is obscured. How do I rectify this?
- In particular, how do I calculate the pixel-coordinate of the uppermost pixel below the tab?
- More generally, is it possible to display a JFrame without a tab in the first place, thereby removing the problem?

Comment: From manual testing, I believe that the *actual (0,0) coordinate is (10,45). However it would be useful if we could just get Java to recognize this automatically.

Comment: *"When one plots points on the JFrame, one naturally assumes that (0,0) corresponds the the top-left pixel available below the tab"* I sure don't. On a wider issue, don't extend `JFrame` (for this and a variety of other reasons). Instead use a standard `JFrame`, and extend a `JPanel` for custom painting. BTW - I'm sure this is a duplicate, but could not be bothered finding one of the (many) instances.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're drawing directly on the `JFrame` which is a top-level window and I don't *think* it supports custom painting in a predictable manner, at least the behaviour seems quite erratic like you've described in your question.

Typically you'd use a `JPanel` and place it in the `JFrame`, like so:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        setSize(960, 960);
        setTitle("Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setContentPane(new JPanelTest());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main t = new Main();
    }

    class JPanelTest extends JPanel {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawLine(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

[image]